# Let $G$ be a group, and let $n\in\mathbb Z$. Show that $(ab)^n=a^nb^n\iff(ab)^{1-n}=a^{1-n}b^{1-n}$.

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group, and let $n\in\mathbb Z$. Show that $(ab)^n=a^nb^n\iff(ab)^{1-n}=a^{1-n}b^{1-n}.$

For the $"\implies"$ direction, let's assume $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$, and let's consider the inverse of $ab$. We can write $(ab)^{-n}=b^{-n}a^{-n}$. If we multiply by $ab$, we get
$$
(ab)^{1-n}=(ab)(ab)^{-n}=(ab)b^{-n}a^{-n}=ab^{1-n}a^{-n}.
$$

But now I need commutativity to conclude the proof. Could someone help me with the last step?

Comment: When $n=2$ we have $abab=a^2b^2$ permultiply by $a^{-1}$ and post multiply by $b^{-1}$. We have commutativty of $a$ & $b$ ! Sorry just realised you want the implication the other way ... ignore this.

Comment: Do you mean $(ba)^{1-n}=b^{1-n}a^{1-n}$?

Comment: @Jason It might have been a typo in my book. Assume they really meant $(ba)^{1-n}=b^{1-n}a^{1-n}$. How can I show that? I seem to have the same problem then: $(ba)^{1-n}=(ba)(ba)^{-n}=(ba)a^{-n}b^{-n}=ba^{1-n}b^{-n}$.

Comment: It would also be interesting to know if there is a counter example to the original claim.

Comment: @Qudit The group $\langle x,y\,|\,x^2y^2=yxyx\rangle$ should probably do it, but I'm not 100%.

Comment: @Jason For which $n$ are you claiming that that group is a counterexample?

Comment: @GregMartin $n=3$ - we have $(xy)^3=x(yxyx)y=x^3y^3$, but I see no reason why we would expect $(xy)^{-2}=x^{-2}y^{-2}$.

Comment: @Jason Indeed, $(xy)^{-2} = x^{-2} y^{-2}$ if and only if $x^3$ and $y^2$ commute.

Comment: @arctictern Please don't be mad. I know you said you solved it for the case $(ba)^{1-n}=b^{1-n}a^{1-n}, but I contacted my teacher as well, and he told me it was solvable and I should keep on trying (which was nonsense, in hindsight), so I thought I would give it a last try at the forum. The source is a syllabus in Dutch on Algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the book has a typo, we prove $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ if and only if $(ba)^{1-n}=b^{1-n}a^{1-n}$. Left and right multiply $(ab)^n$ by $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ respectively and we get $(ba)^{n-1}$. This follows since
$$(ab)^n=abab\ldots ab$$
for $n$ positive, and by taking inverses for $n$ negative. Thus we have
$$(ba)^{n-1}=a^{n-1}b^{n-1}.$$
Take inverses to get one implication. Can you do the other yourself?

Comment: I don't see why $a^{n-1}b^{n-1}=(ba)^{n-1}$. We only know it holds for $n$ and $-n$. How did you show it holds for $n-1$?

Comment: Assume $n>0$. Look at my expression for $(ab)^n$ - it should be clear that $a^{-1}(ab)^nb^{-1}=(ba)^{n-1}$.

Comment: I can see that $a^{-1}(ab)^nb^{-1}=a^{n-1}b^{n-1}$, but how do you defend the second equality?

Comment: We know $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$, so $a^{n-1}b^{n-1}=a^{-1}(ab)^nb^{-1}=a^{-1}a^nb^nb^{-1}$.

Comment: I still don't see how this shows that $a^{n-1}b^{n-1}=(ba)^{n-1}$. Because $(ba)^{n-1}=(ba)^n(ba)^{-1}=b^na^na^{-1}b^{-1}=b^na^{n-1}b^{-1}$. But maybe I'm just tired and I'll see it tomorrow.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made typos in my last comment and it was quite useless. From the line $(ab)^n=abab\ldots ab$, we have $a^{-1}(ab)^nb^{-1}=a^{-1}abab\ldots abb^{-1}=bab\ldots a=(ba)^{n-1}$. Thus, $a^{n-1}b^{n-1}=a^{-1}a^nb^nb^{-1}=a^{-1}(ab)^nb^{-1}=(ba)^{n-1}$.

Comment: Ohhhh! Thank you so much, I see it now!

Answer (score 1):

Also, to show that the statement to be proved (as given in the source) is false, consider the following example . . .

In $S_5$, using cycle notation, let $a = (1\;2\;3\;4\;5)$, and let $b = (2\;4\;5\;3)$.

Then by direct calculation, it can be verified that 
$$(ab)^3 = a^3b^3$$
$$(ab)^2 \ne b^2a^2$$
hence
$$(ab)^{-2}\ne a^{-2}b^{-2}$$