# Prove that $(ab)^\mathrm{n-1}$ = $b^\mathrm{n-1}*a^\mathrm{n-1}$ where n > 1 is a fixed integer

Tags: abstract-algebra

For all $a,b$ in a group G, show $(ab)^\mathrm{n-1}$ = $b^\mathrm{n-1}*a^\mathrm{n-1}$  where **n > 1  is** **a** **fixed integer**. Given $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$

I took inverse on both sides and got $a^n b^n = b^n a^n$ but unable to proceed further.

My book solution has straightaway started with first step as $[b^\mathrm{-1}(ba)b]^\mathrm{n} = b^\mathrm{-1}(ba)^nb$

I don't get how this step is reached.

P.S. : My previous similar question has been marked as duplicate with [Let $G$ be a group, and let $n\in\mathbb Z$. Show that $(ab)^n=a^nb^n\iff(ab)^{1-n}=a^{1-n}b^{1-n}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185499/let-g-be-a-group-and-let-n-in-mathbb-z-show-that-abn-anbn-iffab1) I am re-asking to clarify that $n$ in this question belongs to any integer whereas mine has a fixed value. Also, I am unable to derieve my own solution even after doing the steps mentioned in same.

Comment: There isn't any difference between saying “$n$ is *any* integer” and “$n$ is a *fixed* integer.”   Both are mathematical idioms for the universal quantifier.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to answer that question for you.  My only comment is on your PS request for clarification.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang if "n" is any integer, I can use n = 2 in my question, get simple commutative relation and make my life much easier. However, such an approach should be incorrect if "n" is fixed

Comment: The questions are identical, taking the inverse of $(ab)^{n-1}$. In both questions, $n$ is a fixed integer, say $n=5$. Then $(ab)^{5}=a^5b^5$ is equivalent to $(ab)^4=b^4a^4$, because $(ab)^{-4}=a^{-4}b^{-4}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ for *all* $a,b\in G$, then it is *also valid for all $b,a$*:

$$(ba)^n=b^na^n$$

or

$$\underbrace{(ba)(ba)(ba)\cdots (ba)(ba)}_{n}=\underbrace{bbb\cdots bb}_{n}\underbrace{aaa\cdots aa}_{n}$$

Cancelling one $b$ on the left and one $a$ on the right produces the desired equality:

$$\underbrace{(ab)(ab)(a\cdots b)(ab)}_{n-1}=\underbrace{bb\cdots bb}_{n-1}\underbrace{aaa\cdots a}_{n-1}$$

i.e. $(ab)^{n-1}=b^{n-1}a^{n-1}$, as desired.

As for the first step in your book, it follows from a more general statement $(b^{-1}ab)^n=b^{-1}a^nb$, which can be proven by induction on $n$. Or, just notice that:

$$(b^{-1}ab)^n=\underbrace{b^{-1}abb^{-1}abb^{-1}ab\cdots b^{-1}ab}_n=b^{-1}\underbrace{aa\cdots a}_nb=b^{-1}a^nb$$

as all pairs $bb^{-1}$ cancel each other.

Answer (score 1):

1) Note that for any $m\geq 1$, you have (induction on $m$)

$$(b(ab)b^{-1})^m=b(ab)^mb^{-1}=(ba)^m$$

2) In addition, for $m=n$, you have $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$.
Hence $b(a^n b^n)b^{-1}=(ba)^n$. Simplifying by $ba$ give the result.